# "Invalid initializer" error

Tags: c

Why doesn't this compile? I get:

> [Error] invalid initializer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    char s[100] = (i == 2)? "botton":"bottle";
    printf ("%c", s[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Per the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.7.9, an array of `char` may be initialized with a string literal or a brace-enclosed list of initializers.  A conditional expression is neither one of those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiling with `-Wall` shows the error:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:5:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
    char s[100] = (i == 2)? "botton":"bottle";
         ^
1 error generated.
```

However, you can initialize with `strcpy()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    char s[100] = {0};
    strcpy(s, (i == 2) ? "botton" : "bottle");
    printf("%c\n", s[0]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When the variable `s[]` is initialized, the initialization value must be known at compile-time. The equality test `(i == 2)` occurs at run-time, thus it cannot generate a valid initializer.

You can, however, use `char *s`, because you can change the value of a pointer at run-time:

```
char *s = (i == 2) ? "botton" : "bottle";
```

You cannot, however, use `static char *s` with this initializer, because it is not a constant at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, thats correct, but shouldn't `char s[] = ( (i == 2)? "botton":"bottle" );` work

Comment: @haris that has the same issue

Comment: But i checked, `char* s = ( (i == 2)? "botton":"bottle" );` is working.

Comment: An array is not a pointer, though they may behave similarly in certain respects.

Comment: Doesn't `(i == 2)? "botton":"bottle";` evaluate to a string literal?

Comment: @CoolGuy, thats what. So it should also work with `char s[]`

Comment: @Olaf i am using gcc

Comment: Clang gives the error `crazy.c:7:10: error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal`. won't the right side of that expression give a string literal.

Comment: @haris: please read my answer.

Comment: @CoolGuy No, it evaluates to a `const char*`. Nothing evaluates *to* a literal; a literal is a textual - literal - representation for a value.  Similarly, `(i == 2) ? 34 : 56;` doesn't evaluate to an integer literal, but to an `int` (whose value is either 34 or 56).

Comment: @molbdnilo: No, it evaluates to a `const char *`

Comment: @Olaf I'm stuck in "old" C ;-)

Comment: When the variable `s[]` is initialized, the initialization value must be known at compile-time. The equality test `(i == 2)` occurs at run-time, thus it cannot generate a valid initializer.

Comment: @molbdnilo,@Alex, Thanks. I got it. I think you should add that into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The initializers for an array must be constant initializer-list. `s` being a `char`-array [requires](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) a string-literal or a constant array-initializer.

gcc has an extension, allowing auto-variables to be initialized with non-constant expressions, so it might work for gcc. Other compilers (e.g. clang) might(!) also allow this. Either way, you need to have extensions enabled.

This is true for all ISO-C versions (links are for C11).

You [can](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11), however, use `char *s` (`const char *` if you only use string-literals). This allows to use a normal expression, including non-constant.

Comment: Should this work then `char s[] = ( (2 == 2)? "botton":"bottle" );`??

Comment: @haris: I think so (cannot test right now). C11 seems to allow variable initializers for `auto`.

Comment: The initializer for an array cannot be an arbitrary expression, constant or not. It must be a list of initializers or a string literal (for a char array). C11 does not change this.

Comment: @interjay: Already edited. Just took some time to lookup in the standard. Please remove the DV.